# For how long my blue card is valid once I resign from my current job?

Tags: germany, german-residents, blue-card

I'm an Indian National staying in Germany on a Blue card. Now I'm about to resign from my current job and move to the US for a new one.

My question is, for how long will my blue card be valid? Can I use it for visiting the EU as a tourist at an later point?

Comment: Note that the OP for this question is a visa national, while the OP for the other question is a non-visa national. I do not know if that makes any difference, but just pointing it out as something to consider when voting to close.

Comment: I’m no expert but I’d imagine your Blue Card will be cancelled if you are leaving Germany to work in the US. But you should ask this question on Expatriates

Comment: If you do ask this elesewhere add relevant information: issued for a specfic employer ; how long have you had it. In general: if you leave with a permanent entension (such as moving and working in another country) then the residence permit becomes invalid when leaving.

Comment: No, an invalided residence permit cannot be used for visiting the EU.